# Rails4 Koudoku Gem Getting Error : Uncaught Error: You are using a secret key with Stripe.js, instead of the publishable one

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have been trying to integrate Koudoku gem to one of our App where we will have subscriptions. I have started with the builder provided by the gem, and customized the views accordingly. The problem is, I have been getting this error(Client side, javascript) -

"Uncaught Error: You are using a secret key with Stripe.js, instead of the publishable one."
Though I have put it like it's there in the example;

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey("#{Koudoku.stripe_publishable_key}");
```

I have followed the same process given in the example, and above is the error which I get through javascript. And below is the error which I get after form-post;

> The provided key 'pk_test_************************' does not have the
>   required permissions for this endpoint on account
>   'acct_****************'. Having more permission would allow this
>   request to continue.

Can anyone please guide me through this error, please.

Here is whole html from the _card.html.slim

```html
- content_for :koudoku do

  script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"
= form_for @subscription, url: url, html: {id: 'payment-form', class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  .form-group
    label Card Number
    .input-icon-wrapper
      input type="text" class="form-control card-number" autocomplete="off" size="20"
  .form-group
    label Expiration (MM-YYYY)
    .input-icon-wrapper
      .col-sm-3
        input type="text" class="form-control card-expiry-month" size="2"
      .col-sm-1
        span
          | -
      .col-sm-3
        input type="text" class="form-control card-expiry-year" size="4"
  .form-group
    label CVC
    .input-icon-wrapper
      input type="text" class="form-control card-cvc" autocomplete="off" size="4"

    .alert.alert-error.payment-errors
    = f.hidden_field :plan_id

  .control-group
    .controls
      - if Koudoku.free_trial?
        button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button"
          | Save Billing Information
      - else
        button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button"
          | Upgrade Your Account
      = link_to "Cancel", owner_subscriptions_path(@owner), class: 'btn'
javascript:
  // All this code taken from Stripe's own examples at:
  // https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms .
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    console.log(">>>> Inside stripeResponseHandler | Status : ", status, " | Response : ", response);
    if (response.error) {
      // show the errors on the form
      $(".payment-errors").text(response.error.message).show();
      $(".submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      var form$ = $("#payment-form");
      // token contains id, last4, and card type
      // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[credit_card_token]' value='" + response['id'] + "'/>");
      form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[last_four]' value='" + response['last4'] + "'/>");
      form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='subscription[card_type]' value='" + response['card_type'] + "'/>");
      // and submit
      form$.get(0).submit();
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("#{Koudoku.stripe_publishable_key}");
    // By default, don't show errors.
    $(".payment-errors").hide();
    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
      // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      console.log(">>>> card-number : ", $('.card-number').val(), " | card-cvc : ", $('.card-cvc').val(), " | card-expiry-month : ", $('.card-expiry-month').val(), " | card-expiry-year : ", $('.card-expiry-year').val());
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Thanks in advance.
Nishant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error involves your javascript saying you're using a secret key, and your ruby saying you're using a publishable key, so I'm assuming that you have them backwards where ever you set `#{Koudoku.stripe_publishable_key}"`. `#{Koudoku.stripe_publishable_key}"` should be the one with `pk_test_...`